# Sort based on second column and list from highest to lowest

Tags: awk, python, sort, bioinformatics, r

```
TGAAACATGCCTTTCACCTCCTGCCATGATTGTGAGGCCT 2
GTGTTGCCCAGGTTGGTTTCAAACTCAGCTCAAGTGATCT 1
GAGACTCCTTCAGGAGACTGGTCCCCTGTCCTCGCCTCTC 3
CATGTTCTCCTGGAAGCCATGTGAGGAAGGCACATCATGG 8
AAGGACATAATCTCATTACTTTTATGGCCGCATAGTATTC 4
AGAGGCAGTGTAAGTGAGGTAGTTGAAAGTATGGACTCTG 2
```

I want to use second column to re-arrange the lines from highest number to lowest

Expected output

```
CATGTTCTCCTGGAAGCCATGTGAGGAAGGCACATCATGG 8
AAGGACATAATCTCATTACTTTTATGGCCGCATAGTATTC 4
GAGACTCCTTCAGGAGACTGGTCCCCTGTCCTCGCCTCTC 3
AGAGGCAGTGTAAGTGAGGTAGTTGAAAGTATGGACTCTG 2
TGAAACATGCCTTTCACCTCCTGCCATGATTGTGAGGCCT 2
GTGTTGCCCAGGTTGGTTTCAAACTCAGCTCAAGTGATCT 1
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. You're getting downvoted because your question lacks own research. For your next question, make sure to include what you've tried and where you're stuck. If you had done that, I'm sure you would have found an answer on this site. Also, you should explain inside your question why you added 4 different language tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort` with `-k` switch:

```
sort -k2 -nr file
```

- `-k2` sort field.
- `-n` numeric sort (not needed here, as in the example numeric and alphabetic would be the same).
- `-r` reverse sorting.